# Ruby CSS works on chrome but doesn't works on FireFox

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some description to show on select  tag on Ruby on Rails. It should be in different color for different description. I handle this by adding CSS. But it works on Chrome well but doesn't works on Firefox.

.html.slim

```
select[name="invoice[budget_line_id]" id="invoice_budget_line_id"]
 - BudgetLine.all.each do |budget_line|
   - if budget_line.budget_balance>=@invoice.total_amount
     |  <option class="color-1" value="
     = budget_line.id
     | ">
     = budget_line.description
   - else
     |  <option class="color-2" value="
     = budget_line.id
     | ">
     = budget_line.description
     = '[ Insufficient budget balance]'
```

.scss

```
select {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  padding: .38rem 1.06rem;
  border-color: #4c84ff40;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: 0.2rem;
  display: block;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  option.color-1{
    color: black;
  }
  option.color-2{
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try moving the options CSS blocks outside the `select` one and see how it goes (it did work for me)?

Comment: Moving it outside select doesn't work for me. Don't know why Firefox doesn't take any CSS for <option> tag.